# re creating SELECT that may require IN

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a table with the following two columns
1) Date, DATE
2) Weather, INTEGER (0=ClearDay, 1=Rain, 2=Snow)

I’d like a SELECT that returns ALL dates when it rained AND snowed within -+ (N,M) days from the day it rained. I.e., if (-+)N,M=1,2 and it rained today (Wed) I’d want today’s date returned if it snowed on any day from Tue to Fri included, assuming only one weather value per day.

- Example 1:
- 1/1/2011, 0
- 1/1/2011, 0
- 1/2/2011, 2
- 1/3/2011, 1
- 1/4/2011, 1
- 1/5/2011, 0
- 1/6/2011, 0

With (-+)N,M=2,1 - return 1/3, 1/4

- Example 2:
- 1/1/2011, 0
- 1/2/2011, 2
- 1/3/2011, 1
- 1/4/2011, 1
- 1/5/2011, 1
- 1/6/2011, 0
- 1/7/2011, 2

With (-+)N,M=1,2, return 1/3, 1/5

Comment: Am using SQLite ... for the moment. Though would think this shouldn't, in theory, be too DBMS-specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do it for you. Replace `@N` with the number of days before and `@M` with the number of days after to check. Note that I assume your table's name is `t`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT rain.date
FROM t AS rain
JOIN t AS snow ON snow.date between rain.date - @N AND rain.date + @M 
    AND snow.weather = 2
WHERE rain.weather = 1
```

I'm having trouble deciding what the correct way is to compare the dates in sqlite. I've tried looking it up but I'm getting conflicting advice. [This sqlite doc page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) made it sound like `julianday` was the best way to compare just the DAY part of a DATE. If the above query doesn't work for you, try this version instead which uses `julianday` to get just the DAY component of the date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT rain.date
FROM t AS rain
JOIN t AS snow ON julianday(snow.date) between julianday(rain.date) - @N AND julianday(rain.date) + @M 
    AND snow.weather = 2
WHERE rain.weather = 1
```

Comment: Was also thinking of ... SELECT * from TabelName t where Weather=1 
AND t.date IN (SELECT date from TableName WHERE date BETWEEN t.date-1 AND t.date+2 AND Weather=2).  I think this should work ... same or better than the above?

Comment: Actually, `JOIN` is much faster. For small datasets the performance difference is negligible, but for large datasets the `IN` method will be at least an order of magnitude slower than using a selfjoin.

Comment: Thanks, my DB will have about 400K rows so depending on where the borderline from small to large is the JOIN may result in a big difference.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (mine or someone else's) if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing a non-equijoin.  (I did this on Oracle, syntax may need to be tweaked)

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
weather_date DATE,
weather NUMBER)
;

INSERT ALL
INTO temp (weather_date, weather) VALUES ('1-jan-2011', 0)
INTO temp (weather_date, weather) VALUES ('2-jan-2011', 2)
INTO temp (weather_date, weather) VALUES ('3-jan-2011', 1)
INTO temp (weather_date, weather) VALUES ('4-jan-2011', 1)
INTO temp (weather_date, weather) VALUES ('5-jan-2011', 0)
INTO temp (weather_date, weather) VALUES ('6-jan-2011', 0)
SELECT * from dual;
```

The following query returns the results you want based on the above dataset.  Change the date offests as needed in the JOIN clause.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT a.weather_date
FROM
    temp a
    JOIN temp b
    ON b.weather_date BETWEEN a.weather_date - 2 AND a.weather_date + 1
WHERE
    a.weather = 1
    AND b.weather = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct date
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t.weather <> t2.weather
              and julianday(t2.date) between julianday(t1.date - N) 
                                         and julianday(t1.date + M)
             )
```

You'll need to replace `t1.date - N` and `t1.date + M` with date arithmetic operators specific to your rdbms. I *think* this is correct for SQLite...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d FROM weather WHERE d IN (
    SELECT date(d, '+1 day') FROM weather WHERE w=1
    UNION
    SELECT date(d, '+2 day') FROM weather WHERE w=1
) AND w IN (1, 2)
```